# Вывод последнего значения для каждой группы в другом столбце

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть такие данные:

```
ACCOUNT  DATA              SUM
-------- ---------- ----------
tED      03.01.2016        500
tED      04.01.2016        600
tED      05.01.2016        100
tED      08.01.2016        900
tED      09.01.2016        700
Bin      09.01.2016        200
Kol      09.01.2016        700
Mod      09.01.2016       3200
Mod      09.01.2016       3600
```

Дальше, есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT distinct
 last_value(account) over(partition by account order by data desc) account,
 last_value(sum) over(partition by account order by data desc) sum
FROM (
 select 
  account, 
  data, 
  sum,
  nth_value(data, 1) over(partition by account order by data desc) cr
 from accounts)x
WHERE data = cr;
```

Он выдает последний депозит для каждого аккаунта.

Как можно переписать запрос, используя только одну оконную функцию?

---

PS В задании было только вывести последний депозит, что я собственно и сделал, а потом ТЗ поменялось, теперь нужно использовать только одну оконную функцию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
select account, data, sum
from (
    select
        a.*,
        row_number() over(partition by account order by data desc) as rn
    from accounts a
) where rn = 1;
```

Еще варианты:

RANK/DENSE_RANK

`select account, sum
from (
    select
        a.*,
        rank() over(partition by account order by data desc, sum) as rn
    from accounts a
) where rn = 1;` (использование dense_rank такое же),

NTH_VALUE

`select account, sum
from (
    select
        a.*,
        nth_value(sum, 2) over(partition by account order by data desc, sum desc) as rn
    from accounts a
) where rn is null;`

LAG

`select account, sum
from (
    select
        a.*,
        lag(data) over(partition by account order by data desc, sum desc) as rn
    from accounts a
) where rn is null;`

Ну и так далее...

Comment: А еще какие-то оконные функции можно использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: @daydark, можно попробовать использовать: RANK, DENSE_RANK, FIRST, FIRST_VALUE, NTH_VALUE, но `ROW_NUMBER`, по-моему, наиболее удобный и естественный вариант... [Список аналитических функций](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

Comment: @daydark, а вы проверяли добавленные вами варианты? "Меня терзают смутные сомнения", что эти запросы вернут не совсем то, что вы ожидаете... PS не могли бы вы добавить ваши варианты решения как собственный ответ?

Comment: эти и еще штук 20 выдают корректный результат. Могу в принципе все их вынести в отдельный ответ

Answer (score 2):

> а потом ТЗ поменялось, теперь нужно использовать только одну оконную функцию

Врядли ТЗ будет содержать, сколько и какими функциями надо достичь результата. Скорее всего это учебное задание. Поэтому, допольню ранее данный и правильный ответ, решением, которое несколько лаконичней и на некоторых сетах данных может быть более эффективным, просто [LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC):

```
select account, max (data) asOfToday,
    max (sum) keep (dense_rank last order by data) deposit
from accounts 
group by account;
```

Даст такой результат:

```
ACC ASOFTODAY     DEPOSIT
--- ---------- ----------
Bin 09.01.2016        200
Kol 09.01.2016        700
Mod 09.01.2016       3600
tED 09.01.2016        700
```